# Does every real number $r\in [0,1]$ have a rational sequence $q_n\to r$ s.t. $q_n$ has (simplified) denominator $n$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This seems pretty trivial but I can't seem to figure it out. I think it's obviously true, given an unconstrained convergent sequence we just have to add some filler elements, but I'm having trouble formulating this formally. Just an idea on how one does this would suffice, no need to write it out fully.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $n$ we set $q_n = \frac{\text{smallest number more than $nr$ coprime to $n$}}n$. Note that the next prime following $nr$ or the next prime following it is coprime to $n$ for large enough $n$ (you can set it arbitrarily for smaller values), and is $nr + o(n)$, so the error converges to 0 and the sequence converges to $r$.

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for! Many thanks!

Comment: Note also that without the restriction to prime numerators, one can get even closer approximations: It is known that the largest gap between two integers coprime to $n$ is asymptotically $O(log^2(n))$, see Jacobsthal function. This is better than any proven bound on largest prime gaps.

Comment: @JoachimKönig Thanks, I was wondering if that's the case